# Reading data from file in console in c

Tags: c

Hi i have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c=' ';
    fp=fopen("E:\data.txt","w");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Write data & to stop press '.' :");
    while(c!='.')
    {
        c=getche();      
        fputc(c,fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\nContents Read:");
    fp=fopen("E:\data.txt","r");
    while(!feof(fp));
    printf("%c",getc(fp));
}
```

And when executing the above code , i have the following output

Output:

```
Write data & to stop press '.' :writing data into the file.

Contents Read:
```

Output doesn't display the contents which i have inputted.

Please help me where did i went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Your primary issue is here:

```
while(!feof(fp));
```

The trailing semi-colon is the complete body of the loop, followed  by a single call to printf.  However,  [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)  for other reasons.

Comment: I have removed the while(!feof(fp)); But when i given inputted text as "writingdata." I am getting "Contents read as w". 
Actually the contents read should be "writingdata."
Pls help me.

Comment: Did you completely remove the loop and leave yourself with just a single call to `fgetc` as an argument to a single call to `printf`?  If so, then the problem is pretty clear.  You still need to loop, you just need to do it correctly.  (just removing the semi-colon will help, but is not correct.)

Answer (score 1):

There is typo here.

`while(!feof(fp));` take you to end of file.

so just remove `;`.

Comment: I have removed the
 while(!feof(fp));
But when i given inputted text as "writingdata."
I am getting "Contents read as w".
Pls help me.


Actually the contents read should be "writingdata."

Comment: remove only semi-colon, not the entire while loop.

Comment: Extremelly sorry , i didnt noticed the semicolon,
But i have gone into file location and opened the file ,when i look into the file , the inputted data is not displayed.